# Make a fixed Div follow just on X axis

Tags: html, css

I have a div positioned fixed:

```
.titles{
position: fixed;
background: #ffffff;
margin-left:-20px;
}
```

However, it's following as well when I'm moving Y axis, and I just want it to follow on the X axis.

Any tip? I'd rather using CSS, if possible. JS is accepted as well.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wAEsg/

Comment: You can't do this with pure CSS afaik.

Comment: Added a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wAEsg/

Comment: Just wondering: *must* this use fixed positioning? Wouldn't [this](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/wAEsg/6/) do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it with Jquery. First set that div to Absolute instead of Fixed, then:

```
var titles = $(".titles"); // cached collection
var leftOffset = parseInt(titles.css('left'));
$(window).scroll(function(){
    titles.css({
        'left': $(this).scrollLeft() + leftOffset
    });
});
```

Comment: Having a selector inside the scroll handler is a bad idea. The scroll event fires rapidly and you're asking the DOM for all the `.titles`over and over. Just save it in a variable in the scope outside and you're golden ;)

Comment: Edited, now the `titles` var is referenced insted of querying the DOM inside the scroll handler.